# Error while using PHP SMTP mailer for Gmail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, smtpclient

> Warning: fputs() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given in C:\xampp\htdocs\JOBPORTAL1\employer\public_html\class.smtp.php on line 215
>   SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenti

My code at 215 Line Is

```
public function Authenticate($username, $password) {
// Start authentication
fputs($this->smtp_conn,"AUTH LOGIN" . $this->CRLF);

$rply = $this->get_lines();
$code = substr($rply,0,3);

if($code != 334) {
  $this->error =
    array("error" => "AUTH not accepted from server",
          "smtp_code" => $code,
          "smtp_msg" => substr($rply,4));
  if($this->do_debug >= 1) {
    echo "SMTP -> ERROR: " . $this->error["error"] . ": " . $rply . $this->CRLF . '<br />';
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here i face the error please help me to resolve this error

Comment: Check what `$this->smtp_conn` is. The error-message is quite clear.

Comment: how i could resolve this issue  in  $this->smtp_conn

Comment: Show the code how you define that property. Its clearly not what you expect it to be.

Comment: You are using a very old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). It's likely that will fix your problem, but it should at least give you a better error message.

Comment: i solve it there was an error in XAMPP configuration